# Pandas Groupby Agg: Get strings that appear the most in column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, group-by

I have a dataframe like this with **IDs** and **Preferences** in a string separated by ', ':

| ID | Preferences |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | banana, apple |
| 1 | banana, apple, kiwi |
| 1 | avocado, apple |
| 2 | avocado, grapes |
| 2 | banana, apple, kiwi |

And I want to group by the ID and get the 2 preferences that appear the most, so the result would be like:

| ID | first_preference | second_preference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | banana |
| 2 | avocado, grapes, banana, apple, kiwi |  |

with 'draws' being concatenated together.

I need to do this on an **aggregated groupby** because I have other columns I need to aggregate too.

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the preferences, first split and expand your DataFrame into a much longer Series. Then, count and rank the number of occurrences, and another `groupby` + `agg` will allow you to join the ties for the first and second prefernences.

The index of this result will be the unique `'ID'` values in your original DataFrame, so you can `concat` this with the results of your other `groupby`  + `agg` operations

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,2,2],
                   'Preferences': ['banana, apple', 'banana, apple, kiwi', 'avocado, apple', 'avocado, grapes',
                                   'banana, apple, kiwi']})
```

---

##### Code

```
# Expand to long Series
s = df.set_index(['ID']).Preferences.str.split(', ', expand=True).stack()

# Within each ID, rank preferences based on # of occurrences
s = (s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(0), s.rename('preference')]).size()
      .groupby(level=0).rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
      .map({1: 'first', 2: 'second'}).rename('order'))

res = s[s.isin(['first', 'second'])].reset_index().groupby(['ID', 'order']).agg(', '.join).unstack(-1)

# Collapse MultiIndex to get simple column labels
res.columns = [f'{y}_{x}' for x,y in res.columns]
```

---

```
print(res)
                        first_preference second_preference
ID                                                        
1                                  apple            banana
2   apple, avocado, banana, grapes, kiwi               NaN
```